# Embedded PPT Deck and jumping to a specific slide

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, powerpoint

I've embedded a PPT into a web part page using the Page Capture Web, which is rendered as an PowerPoint Online Slide deck.  The deck has been built with a "flow" to it and has several links that refer to each different section of the same file.

I've been asked if it's possible to jump to specific decks in this deck as the client is wanting to embed the same deck in several different pages but to have them jump to different pages on each instance. I'm unable to determine what the exact links from within the OWA rendered slide deck are.

Any pointers appreciated.